# Symfony2 multiple logins

Tags: php, security, session, symfony

In a Symfony2 application I have to be able be logged in with a different user in different browser tabs. eg: I have to be logged in as user A in tab 1 and user B in tab 2. (like you do in Gmail for example)

Logging in the user is not our problem. The problem is that the session is shared over the tabs and gets overwritten. So when I log in as user B in tab 2, tab 1 is also logged in as user B.

Private browsing fixes this but is not accepted as a solution.

I'm not sure if there is a clean solution but I want to know how you would solve this before I start hacking a solution. It seems risky to get this right, I don't want to mess up security and introduce a huge hole in the system.

Comment: One way to do it is to go completely stateless and pass SESSION_ID as GET parameter. This was popular way of doing this few years ago but is opened your application to session hijacking...

Comment: Are you using an external login bundle, like FOSUserBundle ? Might solve your problem.

Comment: using multiple domains is an option. eg: id1.user.domain.tld, id2.user.domain.tld where *.user.domain.tld is a catch-all in DNS.

Comment: someone also suggested to store the session id in a user's html5 session storage instead of a cookie, the session storage is "per tab". I didn't try to make this work, because it seems a fragile solution that can break on lots of edge cases.